# Unable to zoom UIImageView in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, zooming

I want to zoom `UIImageView` in `ScrollView` but I do not know how to do this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    var viewInScrollView: UIView = UIView()
    var selectedImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.delegate = self

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(viewInScrollView)
        viewInScrollView.addSubview(selectedImageView)
        selectedImageView.image = UIImage(named: "michael")

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewInScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        selectedImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        scrollView.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)
        viewInScrollView.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)
        viewInScrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width).isActive = true
        viewInScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height).isActive = true

        selectedImageView.anchor(top: viewInScrollView.topAnchor, leading: viewInScrollView.leadingAnchor, bottom: viewInScrollView.bottomAnchor, trailing: viewInScrollView.trailingAnchor)

    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return selectedImageView
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the contentSize of your scrollview? you need to increase contentSize to zoom the imageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `maximumZoomScale`, `minimumZoomScale` to your `scrollView` like following.

`scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.25`
`scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0`

Hope this help!.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to start with [a tutorial example](https://www.raywenderlich.com/560-uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started) for `UIScrollView` zooming. Do it step by step first.

And ....

At a glance, your constraints for `viewInScrollView` are not accurate. The views hierarchy in your project is

```
view -> scrollView -> viewInScrollView -> selectedImageView
```

The constraints for `viewInScrollView` will decide the `contentSize` of `UIScrollView`. When zooming in/zooming out, the `contentSize` will changed. So, it's (top, bottom, left, right) anchor should aligned to `UIScrollView`, not to `view`. So I think the following constraint is wrong.

```
// Not right
viewInScrollView.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)

// It should aligned to `UIScrollView`'s top, bottom, left and right anchors.
```